# How can I set the screen size to 4'7 in in bluestacks emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, screen-size

I am trying to give my emulator a 4'7 screen size (I don't know the height and width dimentions). At the moment I am trying to set it in the AVD manager. Then I am trying to edit one of the available emulator. This isn't working. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 17):

### **Step-1:** In Windows Go to `Run`

[image: Image1]

---

### **Step-2:** This will start the registry editor navigate till `FrameBuffer-> 0` as shown in the snapshot

[image: Image2]

---

### **Step-3:** Change the value `GuestHeight`,`GuestWidth`, `WindowHeight`, `WindowWidth` as shown in images below

**GuestHeight**

[image: Image3]

---

**GuestWidth**

[image: Image4]

---

**WindowHeight**

[image: Image5]

---

**WindowWidth**

[image: Image6]

---

**FINAL-OUTPUT-IN-EMULATOR**

[image: Image7]

Comment: Buttons/Taps affected. Now I am clicking somewhere and click is taken somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I was just googling for the same issue, and I found these regedits very useful for reaching my goal:

> Adjusting the screen resolution of BlueStack
>
> The resolution can be changed by editing the BlueStack's registry:
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\Height
>
> and
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\Width

found this information [here](http://hkdevtips.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/adjusting-screen-resolution-of-bluestack.html)

To make sure this exactly fits my tiny screen, I went to see my screen resolution

and then I copied that information to these addresses via regedit.

tip: make sure you use decimal values when you paste the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run regedit.exe
2. Set new resolution (in decimal):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\Height

and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0\Width

Kill all BlueStacks processes.

Got this method from this [blog](https://druss.co/2014/08/how-to-bluestacks-change-screen-resolution/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

STEPS:-

1.In Windows Go to Run in Run type -> regedit

Click OK button , after click it will show Registry Editor screen

2. This will start the registry editor navigate till -> Computer-> HKEK_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> BlueStacks -> Guests -> AndroidFrame -> Buffer -> 0

   Here Registry Editor,

   Have four Height and width option

   Make same minor changaes

   a. GuestHeight 720 decimal
   b. GuestWidth  1152 decimal

   this is the default size of GuestHeight,GuestWidth in BlueStack App Player 
   here, not need to change anything.

   Now,give the size of WindowHeight and WindowWidth.

   c. WindowHeight 500 decimal
   d. WindowWidth  700 decimal

   Now you not need to change anything this is the best size.If you are trying
   to chanage WindowHeight and WindowWidth then installed app will be pixelated.

Answer (score 1):

After setting window/guest width/height I still had problems with my screen being cut off.

I resolved it quitting all instances of Bluestacks running `HD-Quit.exe` and `HD-QuitMultiInstance.exe` (to make sure) located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks`. System restart may help too

Answer (score 0):

There a couple solutions you can try:
There is a tool called stacksTweak around the forums which you can google. It didn't work for me though (it worked for others so it is worth trying). What worked for me was to tweak some registers myself. Here's a tutorial on that:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1298332

Answer (score -1):

registry edit only resize the screen and then you are left with smaller screen. but the problem is that the content of the app is not configured accordingly as it happen in real mobile. also it doesn't provide you the scroll bar at top or bottom to see the screen which is not visible at front.